# Recursive Method For Checking All Possible Values (C)

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm writing a program that reads in an integer value (n), and creates a chess table with those dimensions (nXn). I then have to see if there a way that I could place n queens on this board in such a way that none of them could attack each other (For those of you unfamiliar with chess, Queens can attack any piece that is in the same column or row as them, as well as any piece that sits on a diagonal that passes through the queen). The values are stored in an array (int board[n]), that is initially set to all -1. The value in board[0] would correspond to the row that the queen in column 0 is located at. Initially, all the values are set at -1, which means there is no piece in said row.

I'm trying to find a way in which I could pass every possible set of coordinates (Essentially every possible array of length n, and whose values can range between 0 and n-1) through a method that checks to see if this is a valid way to lay out the pieces, and if there is a layout that works, it must pass that array to a method that visualizes it, like so:

```
* * Q *
Q * * *
* * * Q
* Q * *
```

The methods for checking and outputting are set and working, I just need to figure out how to generate all the possible permutations of the array that stores that coordinates.

EDIT:
Here is the code so far (UPDATED AS OF 2PM, December 6th):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int permutations (int board[],int n, int counter, int index);
int check (int board[], int n);
int printout (int board[], int n, int isValid);
int main() {
  int n, board[n];
  while (1==scanf("%d", &n) && n > 0) {
      int board[] = {-1};
      int isValid = permutations(board,n, 0, 0); 
      printout(board, n, isValid);
}
  return 0;
}
int permutations(int board[],int n, int counter, int index){
board[index] = counter;
int max = n-1;
if ((check(board, n) == 1) && (index == max)){
return 1;
}
if (check(board, n) == 1){
permutations(board, n, 0, ++index);
}
else if (check(board, n) == 0){
counter++;
}
if (counter == n){
return 0;
}  
}
int check(int board[], int n){
int i,j;
int isValid = 1;
for (i=0; i<n && isValid; ++i) {
      if (board[i]==-1) continue;
      for (j=i+1; j<n && isValid; ++j) {
    if (board[j]==-1) continue;
    if ( board[i] == board[j] ||
             board[i]-board[j] == i-j ||
             board[i]-board[j] == j-i )
      isValid = 0;
      }
    }
return isValid;}
int printout(int board[], int n, int isValid){
int i,j;
    putchar('\n');
    for (i=n-1; i>=0; --i) {
      for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
    if (j>0) putchar(' ');
    putchar( board[j]==i ? 'Q' : '.' );
      }
      putchar('\n');
    }
    puts( isValid ? "valid configuration" : "invalid configuration" );
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Start with the first row. Position a queen on the first cell and mark as "attacked" all the cells that queen can move to. Then move to the next row and place a queen on a cell that's not attacked. So on and so forth. Then see if it works with the queen on a different column on that row. Do you want the actual code?

Comment: That would be very helpful. I'm pretty new to C

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. If you show you've done some research, I'd be glad to help. But it seems like you just want someone to do the work for you.

Comment: Even more helpful would be if you attempt to do it, then post the code in case you get stuck so you can get help.

Comment: I'm just stuck on it. I tried using nested for loops to no avail, and now I'm taking a shot a recursion. The question is based off of a previous assignment, which checked to see if the board was valid, but now I've got to find a way to find the values that would make it valid.

Comment: Well there is no loop in your `permutations` function now. Since you mentioned you want a recursive algorithm, what do you have in mind? What would be your base case?

Comment: The base case is that every value is -1 (Meaning there is no piece on that row). I'm not really sure how to go about it. My first though was to add 1 to a single row each time (-1,-1,-1) -> (0,-1,-1) -> (0,0,-1) -> (0,0,0) -> (1,0,0) -> (1,1,0), but I know that it would miss lots of values. I could also increase a single values on each iteration, and only increase that value until it hits the max I.E (0,0,0) -> (1,0,0) -> (2,0,0) -> (0,1,0) -> (1,1,0) -> (2,1,0) -> (0,2,0) Etc. but I'm not sure how to do it, especially if the array is of a varying length

Answer (score 0):

Hint for your homework (recursion):

Start with an empty board and call your recursive routine. Iterate over the board, trying to put a queen on it. If it is attacked then continue. Otherwise call yourself with the board (one more queen now). Iterate over the board, trying to put a queen on it. If it is attacked then continue. Otherwise call yourself...

If you have reached 6 queens, return "success" and unwind the recursion.

If at any point you cannot place another queen on the board, return "failure", remove the queen and continue the iteration from where you called yourself.

This is a "brute force" approach.

Comment: Ok, I'll post my updated code. I tried to implement it, but it keeps defaulting to true.

Answer (score 0):

This code works (here is your homework):

```
int checkBoard(int board[8][8]);
int putQueens(int board[8][8], int nQueens);
void printBoard(int board[8][8]);

int eightQueens(void)
{
    int board[8][8];
    memset(board, 0, sizeof(int)*64);
    if (putQueens(board, 0)) {
        printBoard(board);
        return (1);
    }
    return(0);
}
int putQueens(int board[8][8], int nQueens)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]==0) {
                board[i][j]= 1;
                if (checkBoard(board)) {
                    if (nQueens==7) return(1);
                    if (putQueens(board, nQueens+1)) return(1);
                }
                board[i][j]= 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
int checkBoard(int board[8][8])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                int ii, jj;
                for (ii=i+1; ii<8; ii++) {
                    if (board[ii][j]) return(0);
                }
                for (jj=j+1; jj<8; jj++) {
                    if (board[i][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i+1, jj=j+1; ii<8 && jj<8; ii++, jj++) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i-1, jj=j-1; ii>0 && jj>0; ii--, jj--) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i-1, jj=j+1; ii>0 && jj<8; ii--, jj++) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
                for (ii=i+1, jj=j-1; ii<8 && jj>0; ii++, jj--) {
                    if (board[ii][jj]) return(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (1);
}
```

I am just not happy with checkBoard; it can be made more elegant. (Your homework).

So that you have learnt: please place a comment explaining where you went wrong in your code and what you learned from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Marginal error in `main()`: Don't define the variable length array `board[n]` before `n` has been input.
Now to the algorithm: For the assigned task (place `n` queens on the board) there is no point in generating layouts which contain less than `n` queens. So initialize the `board` with some permutation that can potentially be rearranged to a valid layout; I chose `{ 0, 1, 2 .. n-1 }` below. I rewrote the function `permutations()` as wanted to *generate all the possible permutations of the array* `board[]`, *and if there is a layout that works, ... pass that array to a method that visualizes it* (your original `printout()`). In addition the function increments a counter for the valid layouts - I find it interesting how the count varies for different values of `n`.

```
int n, counter; // counter: counts valid layouts found

void permutations(int board[], int j)
{   // generate all possible permutations of board[0..j-1]
    int i = --j;
    if (i <= 0)
    {   // arrived at one permutation - check it, and print if valid
        if (check(board, n)) ++counter, printout(board, n, 1);
        return;
    }

    permutations(board, i);
    while (i--)
    {
        int k, x;
        for (k = j; k > i; --k)
            if (board[i] == board[k]) break;
        if (k > i) continue;

        x = board[i], board[i] = board[j], board[j] = x;
        permutations(board, j);
        x = board[i], board[i] = board[j], board[j] = x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (1==scanf("%d", &n) && n > 0)
    {
        int board[n], i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) board[i] = i;
        counter = 0, permutations(board, n); 
        printf("%d valid configurations\n", counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```